# Clone git repo not working in vscode although git command succeeds (SSH)

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, ssh, rsa

Trying to clone a git repository in Windows vscode from a private Linux host (SSH / client RSA key)

What is OK:

- In a command prompt, `git clone ssh://gituser@...` (passphrase request)
- connection with the vscode "Remote-SSH" extension (passphrase request)

The problem:

- In vscode, "Clone Git Repository..." fails without passphrase request: "Permission denied, please try again.gituser@192.168.1.18: Permission denied (publickey,password).fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

[image: succesful git clone]

[image: vscode git clone request]

[image: vscode error]

host sshd log:

```
...
debug1: userauth-request for user gituser service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: userauth_pubkey: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable for RSA SHA256:DlTkOFDZK... [preauth]
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1033/100 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /var/services/homes/gituser/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /var/services/homes/gituser/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1 RSA SHA256:DlTkOFDZK...
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Postponed publickey for gituser from 192.168.1.132 port 5xxx1 ssh2 [preauth]

debug1: userauth-request for user gituser service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for gituser: Permission denied
Failed none for gituser from 192.168.1.132 port 5xxx1 ssh2: RSA SHA256:DlTkOFDZK...
debug1: userauth-request for user gituser service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 3 failures 1 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for gituser: Permission denied
Failed password for gituser from 192.168.1.132 port 5xxx1 ssh2
debug1: Unable to open the btmp file /var/log/btmp: No such file or directory
...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the CMD where the clone does work, type

- `set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -Tv"`
- `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd"`

From there, try and clone again, this time checking what SSH key is actually used in that new VSCode session.

Comment: Resulting ssh log is below
I am on Windows: how can it ask me a passphrase without /dev/tty?
...
debug1: Server accepts key: /c/Users/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:DlTkOFDZK...
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
...
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
...

Comment: @J.P.Duvet Do you need a passphrase-protectyed key in your case? Can you test with one without passphrase?

Comment: Yes, a passphraseless key worked and is a fallback option waiting for the solution